# Invalidate form control with setErrors

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to add an error to a form control (without any validators) and expect an invalid state of the control when rendered. But it is rendered as valid. What am I getting wrong?

Full Example: https://embed.plnkr.co/aYayRFpBBTEzggL0vkXi/

```
const name = new FormControl('A Name');
name.setErrors({ 'something': true });
name.markAsTouched();

const street = new FormControl('A Street');

this.formData = new FormGroup({
  name,
  street
});
```

My expectation is that not only "street" is invalid but "name" should be also invalid (because it has the error "something")...

Thanks!

Comment: Setting the error in a setTimeout works but I guess that can't be the solution :(

Comment: perhaps you need to also `markAsDirty`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a Reactive form control's errors are reset after its rendering in the view.

Its likely that once the input boxes are added in the view, Angular checks for the validations and then resets your control errors because it doesn't see any in the form control (there are no Validators set).

If you do your changes under `ngAfterViewInit()`, it will work fine. (But yes, then you will have to call detect changes after that or else you will be getting "expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" errors).

```
constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
  const name = new FormControl('A Name');

  const street = new FormControl('A Street');

  this.formData = new FormGroup({
    name,
    street
  });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.formData.get('name').setErrors({'something': true})
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

See an example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/RgEoRPF8jSp203xfwiFS?p=preview

Comment: Another gotcha I have experienced is if your form is removed from the DOM (i.e. ngIf) after you had used `.setErrors()` those changes will be lost/reset once the form is back.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I found an ok solution:
https://embed.plnkr.co/kop9jGFR6y5C4SnxXgcL/

You can just set a "fake" validator instead of setting an error:

```
const name = new FormControl('A Name', {
  validators: () => {
    return { 'something': true };
  }
});
```

But I still don't get why it's not working the initial way :(